# Why is my collection appearing in the list of collections after being droped?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to create a fullstack aplication using react express and mongodb. in this aplication i'm trying to delete a collection from my database and reload the page, but the collection keep showing in the list of collections. Even if i try to delete the collection from mongoDB shell the collection reappears when i load my frontend page, specifically when i use the the get method to load the items from the data base.

These are my drop collection and my get functions.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

async function dropCollection(collection){

    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mytubeDB", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

    await mongoose.connection.db.collection(collection).drop();

    await mongoose.connection.close();

}

module.exports.dropCollection = dropCollection;
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const videoSchema = require("./videoSchema.js");

async function getAllItems () {

    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mytubeDB", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });   
   
    let collections = await mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray();

    let collectionsName = collections.map(collection => collection.name);

    console.log(collectionsName)

    collectionsName.sort();

    let items = [];

    for (let collection of collectionsName) {
        const myModel = mongoose.model(collection, videoSchema, collection);
        const collectionItems = await myModel.find();
        items.push(collectionItems);
    }

    let object = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < items.length ; i++){
        object[collectionsName[i]] = items[i];
    } 

    await mongoose.connection.close();

    return object;

}

module.exports.getAllItems = getAllItems;
```

Comment: Does the collection being recreated have the same name as another, except with an 's'  on the end?

Comment: No, the collection has exactly the same name as the one that was deleted

Comment: You might try enabling auditing on the database server so you can seen exactly when and how it is being recreated